# Code blocks output console has stopped working

Tags: c, string, codeblocks

Whenever i declare a varible as char and scan it as string "%s" my output console crashes. Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[20];
    int i;
    printf("Enter a name ");
    scanf("%s",&a);
    for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
    {
        a[i] = toupper(a[i]);
        i++;
        printf("%s\n",toupper(a[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&a);` --> `scanf("%19s",&a);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second `i++;` inside the `for` loop body may cause the index to point off-by-one then, `printf("%s\n",toupper(a[i]));` will be out of bound access which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You can remove the `i++` from inside the loop body.

Next, `toupper(a[i])` returns an `int`, which is invalid for `%s` format specifier, which again invokes UB.

That said,

- to prevent buffer overflow from excessive long input, it's best to limit the input length with `scanf()`,
- You don't need to pass the address of an array, just the array name will be sufficient

So, overall, you should write

```
scanf("%19s",a);
```

Comment: `scanf("%19s",&a);` should be `scanf("%19s", a);`.

Comment: @mch Thanks, noted. :)

Comment: Thanks alot:), btw output of this code is suppose to b a certain pattern, if String entered is, morning, expected output should be Morning
MOrning
MORning
MORNing
MORNIng
MORNINg
MORNING

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems in the loop where you use `toupper` and print.

The first is that you increment the variable `i` *twice* in the loop.

The second problem is the `printf`:

```
printf("%s\n",toupper(a[i]));
```

Here you ask `printf` to print a string, but as argument you give it a single character (actually an `int`, [`toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper) returns an `int`). Use the `"%c"` format specifier to print a single character.

By the way, you don't need to call `toupper` when printing, as the character should already be in upper-case because of the previous assignment.

Answer (score 0):

Your printing loop is mis-behaving and giving you undefined behavior:

```
printf("%s\n",toupper(a[i]));
```

is passing `toupper(a[i])` to `printf()`'s `%s` format specifier, which requires a `char *` not a plain `char`. That triggers undefined behavior.

There's no point in printing each character one by one, instead convert the entire string to upper case, then print it once:

```
for(i = 0; a[i] != '\0'; ++i)
{
    a[i] = (char) toupper((unsigned char) a[i]);
}
printf("%s\n", a);
```

The casts around `toupper()` are sometimes needed since it takes and returns `int`, and you want to be a bit careful about when converting to/from characters.

Notice that I factored out the call to `strlen()`, this might be a bit "too clever" but it's how I would expect this code to be written. If we're going to loop over the characters, there's no need to compute the length separately.